# in_array is not finding values that are in the array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting strange results when trying to check a `$_GET` variable against a whitelist array. The variable is in the array but `in_array` is not finding it. I'll descibe what's happening as best I can.

The `$_GET` vars are set from option/select choices, three altogether.  Only one of the options is giving me a problem. To run a `SELECT` query, there have to be at least two options chosen.  Any combination of the other two options works as expected.

To get the option/select lists I have a `SELECT` query retrieving a record subset.

From that recordset I use a `foreach` loop to get the various values to populate the select tags. So the select values are populated by values from the db table. The whitelist arrays are copied from the db.

I check any `$_GET` vars against the whitelist arrays. The option in question can be a comma-delimited string (eg. 'Italian,Pizza' or 'American, Barbeque, Sandwiches').

To get the select value list for this option I use `implode` to create a comma-delimited list of each category, then use `explode` to create an array, then use `array_unique` to get an array with single instances of each category. When echoing this array everything is right (it populates the select choices correctly).

`implode` outputs:

`Italian,Pizza,Italian,Pizza,Italian,Pizza,Italian,Italian,Sandwiches,Italian,Pizza,Italian`

`explode` outputs:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Italian
        [1] => Pizza
        [2] => Italian
        [3] => Pizza
        [4] => Italian
        [5] => Pizza
        [6] => Italian
        [7] => Italian
        [8] => Sandwiches
        [9] => Italian
        [10] => Pizza
        [11] => Italian
    )
```

`array_unique` outputs:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Italian
        [1] => Pizza
        [8] => Sandwiches
    )
```

So, the URL can be like:
`../search.php?var_src=Sandwiches&city_src=Cityname`

To sanitize the `$_GET` vars:

```
    if((isset($_GET['var_src'])) && in_array($_GET['var_src'], $var_array)) {
        $var_sort = $_GET['var_src'];
    }
```

Again, `$var_array` is an array copied from the db table.

This is where the code stops because the `$_GET` var is not being found in the array.

If I change one of the db records to just one category value (eg. 'Sandwiches') and select that option in the list, then the results are as expected. However, if the record has more than one category value (each of which is in the whitelist array) like 'Pizza,Sandwiches', then neither of them work.

The kicker is that if I include the category value 'Italian', whether alone or with other values in the db record, and select for this value, then it works. I have no idea why.

So the code works if that particular value ('Italian') is selected whether or not others are included as a comma-delimited string for the record, and does not work with other values where there are more than one associated with the record.

I confirmed that the offending value is in the URL and so should work with the code above (in_array($_GET['var_src'], $var_array)).

Also, I don't know why changing the db record would have an effect because the sanitizing against the whitelist happens before selecting records based on the passed values. As far as I can tell, `in_array` is just not finding legitimate values in the array.

Hope I haven't made this confusing. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Question was so long I did not wont to read it - haha. One thing I noticed, though, your url ../search.php?var_src=Sandwiches?city_src=Cityname has invalid format. 2 question marks, the second one should be &

Comment: I can asure you that `in_array` works - it's something you do, that is causing the issue. Try `var_export` the input from `$_GET` and have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the URL. Also, just tried `var_export` and it outputs the `$_GET` var as expected, but `$var_sort` is still not being set -- `var_export` outputs `false` (the vars are set to `false` initially). I know `in_array` works as does the code that sets `$var_sort` because I use the same code for the other two options. Can't figure out what's happening here though.

Comment: Hi, from what I just read in php manual for `in_array`, it is case sensitive function. Simply do this before your comparation: `var_export($var_array); var_export($_GET);` - if your variables differs, you cannot use in_array, search for them in the `for` loop instead.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a case sensitive issue. The select values come from a set in the db table. I copied that set for the whitelist array. I've confirmed that the var in the URL is correct case-wise. I use the same code block (adjusted for the different vars) to sanitize the other vars by checking against their own whitelist arrays and they work just fine. The only difference with the problem one is how I get the array of select vars, which I posted. The `array_unique` output looks fine, but the behavior of the sanitizing code is inconsistent.

Comment: `$var_array` is hard-coded on the page. This is where the code is failing: `if((isset($_GET['var_src'])) && in_array($_GET['var_src'], $var_array))`. I've confirmed that the `$_GET` var is an exact match for a value in the `$var_array` which looks like 'Italian','Pizza','Sandwiches'. I still can't figure out why the var is not found in the array.

Comment: Only possible reason I can think of are spaces - like you posted above in 'American, Barbeque, Sandwiches'. You can use `trim()` to remove them.

Comment: Thanks, but I already checked for whitespace in the array. The behavior is just bizarre. If a db record has 'Pizza,Sandwiches' (one string) in the column, and the `$_GET` var is either 'Sandwiches' or 'Pizza', the sanitizing code fails. If I change the record to just 'Sandwiches' for example, it works. I have no idea why changing the db record would affect the sanitizing code because it is simply checking a `$_GET` var against a hard-coded array *before* the db query. I'm thinking there must be something in the flow of my code that's buggy, but I just can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will help you, try to change it like in this example:

```php
$opt = array( 'Italian,Pizza' , 'American, Barbeque, Sandwiches');
$opts = implode(',',$opt);
$opta = explode(',',$opts);
foreach ($opta as $key=>$value) {
    $opta[$key]=trim($value);
}
$opta = array_flip($opta);
var_export($opta);
//now test it simply with isset:
$val = trim($_GET['var_src']);
echo isset($opta[$val])? 'yes':'no';
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much Stano. Works perfectly. Still not sure why this works and mine did not since I trimmed whitespace. Array_flip? Anyway, thanks again.